# How to convert SOAP web service to REST web service in Mule

Tags: rest, soap, wsdl, mule, esb

I would like to convert SOAP ws to REST. Is there any elegant solution to this problem?

REST should take input in json format.

```
{key:value}
```

This json should be put inside Body/Order/data tags:

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <myApp:Order>
    <data>{key:value}</data>
  </myApp:Order>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess Mule ESB should be best in doing this.

Step 1 : You can expose a rest service via http endpoint which should accept your JSON.

Step 2: Then a Custom Transformer can be used to prepare the SOAP request for the SOAP service which needs to be called.

Step 3: OutBound Call to SOAP Web-Service

Step 4: Transformer to convert your SOAP Response from previous out-bound call to JSON response.

The response will be sent back to the client which calle dthe Rest Endpoint.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I was hoping for single magical block which will solve all my problems. Anyway, thank you for answer.

Answer (score 2):

It may be too late to answer this question but it worth to have look on strongloop and its loopback-soap-connector. Check This out this article [Soap into apis with loopback-node-js](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/soap-into-rest-apis-with-loopback-node-js/). You can Extend a model to wrap/mediate SOAP operations. It works like a charm and with very reliable performance!

Comment: You should include a summary of that article in case the link ever goes down.

Answer (score 1):

For asp.net/ Visual Studio, you need to do
File --> New Project --> Select **Online** from the left panel --> You will find Soap to Rest Converter

I hope that will work.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to call a SOAP Web service using a REST web service, please read this article at https://www.wsdltophp.com/Blog/Call-any-SOAP-Web-service-using-a-REST-Web-service