# Is spring integration is suited for enterprise application integration?

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-integration

We are designing a Java middleware web application, something like a ESB, such as IBM message broker or mule.
We have many Oracle EBS interfaces(soap web services), and now the salesforce CRM wants to call the EBS interfaces through the middleware application.
Slaesforce CRM calls the middleware by rest json, and the middleware calls EBS by SOAP webservice. The picture below helps you know my meanings.
[image]
We have struggled many days to design the middleware with Spring Integration. But we found it difficult to do this. We still need to generate a jar file(by CXF) for every EBS interface(each wsdl with a jar file), and call the EBS interface by the traditional web service way.
We do not want to generate the webservice client jar files for each EBS interface. Is spring integration suitable for this(no generating the jar files for each WSDL, just some configuration or not much coding)? If not, can you suggest some other product else?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the SOAP interaction Spring Integration provides the WS module which is fully based on the Spring WS project.

I don't see reason to generate something, if you just can use the Spring Integration's `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` to call that Oracle ESB service.

For this purpose you just need to know which XML to build for the request and which to parse from the response.

Seems for me for this purpose it would be enough for you to know the service WSDL and investigate it from the SOAP UI.

If I were you I'd just forget the CXF when we are with Spring :-).

Comment: Thanks Artem for your answer. You means I can call the Oracle EBS service by Spring WS without generating the jar files? But the Oracle EBS interface soap request xml is very complex, few useful nodes with many useless nodes.

Comment: Correct. So, I guess you really may have some XML template for the `useless` tag and insert there just `useful` with the same Spring Integration and its XML module!

Answer (score 0):

An API gateway is one product which can be used here. Typically, it acts as a proxy between the client and the applications, but it can also do transformation between JSON and XML, which is what would happen in a REST to SOAP conversion.

MuleESB, although not a gateway can also be used for this purpose, see this link [How to convert SOAP web service to REST web service in Mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914842/how-to-convert-soap-web-service-to-rest-web-service-in-mule)

Answer (score 0):

We did this by ourselves.
We developed the middleware by ourselves with Java.
We used java with freemarker template to convert the json request to required soap envelope body. Then used apache httpclient to call the web service(oracle EBS).